# What can we say about convergence of unit sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, vector-spaces

Suppose that $\{x_v\}_{v=1}^{\infty}\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\lim_{v\to\infty} x^v = \infty$. What can we say about convergence of $\{\frac{x^v}{\Vert{x^v}\Vert}\}_{v=1}^\infty$?

I did this:
$$ \lim_{v\to\infty} x^v = \infty \Rightarrow \forall x\in\mathbb{R}^n, \exists\epsilon\gt0, \forall V\in\mathbb{R}, \exists v\geq V s.t. |x^v - x| \geq\epsilon$$
But $ \frac{x^v}{\Vert{x^v}\Vert} $ are unit vectors. I don't know what to do!

Answer (score 1):

In finite dimensional vector spaces every bounded sequence has a convergent subsequence. The sequence $\{\frac{x^v}{\Vert{x^v}\Vert}\}_{v=1}^\infty$ is a normalized sequence and hence bounded.

Comment: So it has a convergent sub sequence? What about convergence of this sequence itself?

Comment: there is nothing else to say, take for example $e_1,e_2,\cdots,e_n,e_1,e_2,\cdots,e_n,e_1,e_2,\cdots$, where $\{e_i\}_{i=1}^n$ is the standarad basis, does this converge ?

Comment: Why is this sequence bounded?

Comment: because all is elements have length $1$, i.e., $\forall i \in \{1,\cdots,n\}\ :\|e_i\| = 1$, do you know what the standard basis in $\mathbb R^n$ is ?

Comment: Yes but is this sequence the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: See my first comment, that was made clear there. The standard basis is a *set*, not a sequence, and there I made a sequence out of it, it is easy man!